# text background color overlay multiply on another image, but text stay solid white

Tags: jquery, html, css

The client sent over a design file that has texts partially on an image, and the background of the text has 'multiply' overlay on the image. However, the texts stay solid white.

I was able to achieve this when the text is only in one line - create separate containers for the background (with `mix-blend-mode: multiply`) and text, dynamically match their width with jQuery, and absolute position them. However, there's this b***h that the texts are dynamic, and could be from 1 to multiple lines.

I'm at my wit's end... any help/thoughts/suggestions would be much appreciated. Thanks!

[image: example]

FYI for anyone wondering why not use rgba or opacity, here's the difference:
[image: multiply]
[image: rgba/opacity]

```js
if($(".transparent_blue").length) {
  var h3width1 = $(".transparent_blue+h3").innerWidth();
  bgwidth1 = h3width1 + 50;
  $(".transparent_blue").width(bgwidth1);
}
```

```css
.top-content {
  position: relative;
}
.text-wrap {
  background-color: white;
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
}
.image-wrap {
  height: 400px;
  width: 60%;
  float: right;
  min-height: 450px;
}
.transparent_blue {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-left: -20px;
  background-color: #0067a3;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}
.transparent_blue_placeholder {
  width: 1px;
  height: 40px;
}
h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 2.7rem;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
h3 {
  font-family: arial;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  line-height: 2;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: -25px;
  padding: 0 25px;
}
.h3-placeholder {
  height: 80px;
  width: 1px;
}
.image-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url("http://eskipaper.com/images/free-street-wallpaper-1.jpg") center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="top-container">
  <div class="text-wrap">
    <h2>the ipsum</h2>
    <div class="transparent_blue">
      <div class="transparent_blue_placeholder">
      </div>
    </div>
    <h3>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos</h3>
    <div class="h3-placeholder"></div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    <h4>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="image-wrap">
    <div class="image-container"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please include your actual code ... if you don't have any clue where to start search about pseudo-elements `:before - :after` and the use of opacity on colors `rgba()`

Comment: @DaniP I tried pesudo-elements, and rgba() won't achieve the same visual effect as the "multiply" overlay in Illustrator.

Comment: Well then include that `code` and all the try on your question we can't assume all you have done

Comment: Just an FYI, [mix-blend-mode/background-blend-mode](http://caniuse.com/#search=mix-blend-mode) are not supported in any version of IE or Edge.

Comment: @APAD1I know... but what other options do I have..?

Comment: Make the text part of the image or tell the client that it is not possible to do what they are wanting to do without having poor browser support.

Comment: @APAD1making text part of the image is not possible... I'll attach the exmaple.

Comment: @DaniP I don't have a clue how to do multiple lines but will show my code of doing the one line.

Comment: You want the text solid white, but the red overlay to be semi transparent?

Comment: @lharby true, but it's not really semi transparent. the opacity is 1, but the blend mode is 'multiply' instead of 'normal'

Comment: if anyone could let me know why this question is downvoted, it would help me in future posts. much appreciated

Comment: @DimSum please include the actual code and make a Stack Snippet, screenshots are frowned upon. In your case the screenshot isn't really worth anything. You've only showed us the CSS class names and a bit of markup. We have no idea what CSS properties you are using for `.transparent_blue_placeholder`.

Comment: @hungerstar  thanks

Comment: So, in that case my suggestion is to make a 1px x 1px png with the opacity settings you require. So presumably black at 60% should work (or something close to it). Then you can set this as the background property to the text, and use padding. I don't think you will truly mimic the blend option from an image editing tool, but you should be able to get very close to it.

Comment: I have made something crude here: https://jsfiddle.net/lharby/rpme2dsr/ if you want a red background you can create all the settings here: http://png-pixel.com/

Comment: @lharby thanks a lot. The red png looks like the closest solution for now.

Comment: @DimSum one major problem I see you having with this is not so much the blend mode but the wrapping of the text (when working with a single line of text). You can get the red background to wrap with the text but I don't know how you're going to get the proper left/right padding where the line breaks. As you can see [in this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0yodj91j/) where the line breaks at _Lorem_ and _ipsum_ the text isn't padded how you're going to want it to.

Comment: @DimSum actually I do know how to handle that but the browser support is not great, you could use [`box-decoration-break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-decoration-break).

Comment: @hungerstar yea I had the same problem before and I remember using this. Thanks for the reminder!!

Comment: _"the texts are dynamic, and could be from 1 to multiple lines"_ - can you be more specific as to what that actually means? Do you have one single line of input text, that you want to break over several lines automatically, based on the width of the element? Or does the text contain line break characters, or even HTML markup like `p` or `br`?

Comment: @CBroe the text is actually the title of events, so it could be any length. It should break to the second, thrid... line when it hits the border of the container/viewport.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the best I could do for a CSS only solution. Browser support is a little light as it uses:

- [`background-blend-mode`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-backgroundblendmode) and
- [`box-decoration-break`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-boxdecorationbreak)

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
p {
  position: absolute;
  width: 75%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 75%;
  transform: translateY( -50% );
}
span {
  display: inline;
  padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 2rem;
  background-image: url( 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mP8z8DwHwAFBQIAX8jx0gAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==' );
  -webkit-background-blend-mode: multiply;
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
  -o-box-decoration-break: clone;
  box-decoration-break: clone;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/250/people/6">
  <p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor.</span></p>
</div>
```

As **@lharby** pointed out to get away with not using `background-blend-mode` you could try to create a small 1px x 1px PNG that approximates what you're looking for.

Other than that it looks like JS is going to be required. Have you looked at [`lettering.js`](http://letteringjs.com/)? I haven't used it myself, though it might be a bit more than you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks very much @hungerstar for your effort! I took a quick look at [`lettering.js`](http://letteringjs.com/) but from what I understand, the line wrapping function needs a `<br>` to identify where to break the line. I guess I'll have to push it back to the client that they can have either the design or full browser support.

Comment: Right on. I'm sure you can figure something out with JS, I'm just not sure how much effort would be required to get the JS to handle all the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

> the text is actually the title of events, so it could be any length. It should break to the second, thrid... line when it hits the border of the container/viewport.

Maybe try and just include the text twice - so that you can position one behind the other, like this: https://jsfiddle.net/xfn0dusw/ - note that the clone in the background (meaning, on the z-axis) has the red background color and its text color set to transparent, and the one in the foreground doesn't have any background, just white text. Because of otherwise equal formatting (font properties and padding) they of course take up exactly the same mount of space and break at the same points. The extra div around the cloned text is necessary, so that we can position that one absolutely - positioning the span instead would rob it of its "inline" properties.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  padding: 2em;
  line-height: 2;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: #eee;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}

.clone {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2em;
  left: 2em;
  right: 2em;
}

span {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: .25em 1em;
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
  box-decoration-break: clone;
  color: #fff;
}

.clone span {
  z-index: 0;
  color: transparent;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor.</span></p>
  <div class="clone"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor.</span></div>
</div>
```

I left out all the other stuff here (image, blend mode) - but the idea should be clear: Apply the background color and blend mode to the clone, and it won't affect the text, because that is in the other element.

---

If having the text in there twice should raise any concerns in regard to SEO and/or accessibility, then maybe don't include the cloned text directly in the HTML, but clone and insert it with JS, and/or add `aria-hidden` to hide it from users using assistive technology like screenreaders. (Putting the text into a custom data attribute and then use that as value for a pseudo element/generated content might be another way to get a "clone" to work with.)

Purists might wrinkle their noses about having the text in the document twice; but considering the alternatives - like the graphics department saying, *"well let's just set the whole darn thing as an image then!"*, or applying complex JS logic to artificially break the text into parts - I like the relative simplicity of this approach: Let's let the browser do, what it does best - render text and apply line breaks dynamically depending on available space.

Comment: really cool idea! never thought that way. thanks for your time into this!